# I can't understand the Unexpected behavior of flex (shorthand property)

Tags: html, css, flexbox

I have a hard time understanding flexboxes. This time I can't understand the behavior of flex property here, like how and why is flex behaving like this when put into the container of flexbox (that is .photoblog in this case). Somebody please help me understanding this.

## CSS

```
.photoblog{            /* the container for flexbox */
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    flex-direction: row;
    justify-content: space-between;
    flex: 2 0 10rem;                
}

.image{                        /* flexboxes made through <div>*/
    width: 400px;
    height: 700px;
    margin: 1.2rem;
    object-fit: cover;
    border-radius: 2rem;
    transition: all ease-in 0.3s;
    box-shadow: 0.3rem 0.5rem 1px rgb(59, 58, 58);
}
```

## HTML

```
<body>
    <section id="flex">
        <nav>
            This is my new photo blog.
        </nav>
       
        <div class="photoblog">
            <img src="images/1.jpg" alt="" class="image"><img src="images/2.jpg" alt="" class="image"><img src="images/3.jpg" alt="" class="image">
            <img src="images/4.jpg" alt="" class="image"><img src="images/5.jpg" alt="" class="image"><img src="images/6.jpg" alt="" class="image">
            <img src="images/7.jpg" alt="" class="image"><img src="images/8.jpg" alt="" class="image"><img src="images/9.jpg" alt="" class="image"><img src="images/10.jpg" alt="" class="image">
        </div>
        <hr>
    </section>
</body>
```

I put the flex property in both the **.photoblog** and **.image** one by one. And here are the results. I don't understand the behavior of the property when it is kept into the **.photoblog** section.

[image: when I put the property in .photoblog]

[image: when I put the property in .image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `.image`s aren't flexboxes. The flexbox (aka "flex container") is the element that has `display: flex` (.photoblog in your case). Flex items are the children of the flexbox (So in your case, `.image`s are flex items). The `flex` shorthand property (`flex: 2 0 10rem`) only makes sense when specified on a flex *item*.

Comment: Thank you very much for clearing out of my concept.

Answer (score 0):

If your problem is in first picture, delete these from .photoblog

```css
flex-wrap: wrap;
 justify-content: space-between;
```